# Windows IIS Docker run through CGI

Tags: docker, iis

I have a bit specific web application where there is a custom request handler in dll form.

In IIS I have Sites-Web-MyApp and for Web I add it like this:

[image]

And if I want to run the app this would be a link:

```
http://localhost/MyApp/MyCustomCGI.cgi
```

Is there a way to add this script mapping in Docker using powershell?

I must say I'm totally beginner with Docker and so far I have this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis

RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command Remove-Item -Recurse C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*

WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot

COPY MyApp/ .
```

**Edit**

Another thing I've tried is this:

```
RUN %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/security/isapiCgiRestriction /+"[path='C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test.dll',allowed='True',groupId='Test',description='Test']" /commit:apphost
RUN %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:system.webServer/handlers /+[name='MyCustomCGI.cgi',path='C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test.dll',verb='*',modules='IsapiModule',scriptProcessor='C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test.dll',resourceType='Either']
```

but still without succsess...
I get 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using appcmd.exe under command line tool which did the same configuration as you set in IIS to a default web site:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv> .\appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" /section:system.webServer/handlers /+"[@start,name='MyCustomCGI',path='MyCustomCGI',verb='*',modules='IsapiModule',scriptProcessor='C:\CGI\Test.dll',resourceType='File',preCondition='bitness32,winx86_64']"
```

Compared to your line , I think it maybe you did not add double quotes "[]" on the parameters.  It won’t work without double quotes for me.

[image]

Comment: This is what I get then... `ERROR ( message:Malformed collection indexer; format is [@position,name='value',name2='value2',...].  The @position specifier is optional, and be '@start', '@end', or '@N' where N is a numeric index into the collection. )`

Comment: I tested it works fine, after executing this statement, the above result will appear in web.config.